# how to use annotation directly on pdf using react-pdf Viewer

Tags: reactjs, vite

i Want to add annotation on the pdf , i mean highlighting features etc. i have used plugin to add annotation and highlighter installed using npm, but nothing working. So how can i add annotation specifically highligting feature directly on pdf using reactjs. i dont want any data to store in database etc. extra info: i am using vite engine with react

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Worker, Viewer } from "@react-pdf-viewer/core";
import { ExcelRenderer, OutTable } from "react-excel-renderer";
import { defaultLayoutPlugin } from "@react-pdf-viewer/default-layout";
import "@react-pdf-viewer/highlight/lib/styles/index.css";
import "@react-pdf-viewer/core/lib/styles/index.css";
import "@react-pdf-viewer/default-layout/lib/styles/index.css";
import { backendBaseUrl } from "../config";
function DocumentDrawer({ isOpen, toggle, viewFile }) {
  const newPdfPlugin = defaultLayoutPlugin();
  const [fileType, setFileType] = useState(null);
  const [excelData, setExcelData] = useState(null);
return (
    <div className={`sidebar_content_viewer ${isOpen ? "open" : ""}`}>
      <button className="btn ms-5 btn-primary close-button" onClick={toggle}>
        Close
      </button>
      <div className="slider_inner_contentview">
        <div className="file_container">
          {fileType === "pdf" && (
            <Worker workerUrl="https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@3.9.179/build/pdf.worker.min.js">
              <Viewer
                fileUrl={`${backendBaseUrl}/api/documents/` + viewFile}
                plugins={[newPdfPlugin]}
                defaultScale={1.2}
                preload={true}
              />
            </Worker>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DocumentDrawer;
```

I just want to add permanent highlighting feature on pdf. above is .jsx file

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from your code you may have installed but not followed the user guide https://react-pdf-viewer.dev/plugins/highlight/

> Usage

1. Import the plugin and styles

> import { highlightPlugin } from '@react-pdf-viewer/highlight';

// Import styles

> import '@react-pdf-viewer/highlight/lib/styles/index.css';

2. Create the plugin instance

> const highlightPluginInstance = highlightPlugin(props?: HighlightPluginProps);

The `highlightPlugin()` function takes a `HighlightPluginProps` parameter that consists of the following properties:

Read the docs and if you have further problems raise an issue at https://github.com/react-pdf-viewer/react-pdf-viewer/issues

Comment: Thanks for your time to response. Bur sir i have implemented it before but it shows error like below
[plugin:vite:react-babel] 
G:\reactjsviteproject\frontend\src\admin\Documentdrawer.jsx: Unexpected token (16:56)
19 |     if (viewFile) {
G:/reactjsviteproject/frontend/src/admin/Documentdrawer.jsx:16:56
14 |.....
15 |    const [excelData, setExcelData] = useState(null);
16 |    const highlightPluginInstance = highlightPlugin(props?: HighlightPluginProps);
                                                                                                      ^

Comment: Sir, i have already used import { highlightPlugin } from '@react-pdf-viewer/highlight'; at the top. but it always shows this error. is there any issue if i am using vite engine with react ?

Comment: so sir, can you assist me with that, how can i use annotation in my .jsx file on pdf? i stucked on this point.